# sbt plugins isn't picked up from submodules?

Tags: sbt, multi-module

I'm trying to convert a single module project into two modules with a
root aggregate. Feels like a normal thing to do.

So, to simplify I have removed the second project that I added, but I
do something like:

```
cd myproject
mkdir core
mv * core
```

and then add a build.sbt in myproject like

```
lazy val root = project.in( file(".") ).aggregate(core)
lazy val core = project in file("core")
```

However, trying to build core I get:

> [myproject]/core/build.sbt:22: error: not found: value lessSettings
>   seq(lessSettings:_*)

which is the settings for a plugin added in project/plugins.sbt of the
original project now in

```
[myproject]/core/project/plugins.sbt
```

How come this is not picked up? Can't I have plugins living only in
submodules? cd:ing into core submodule and running sbt it works just fine. Do I have
to move my plugins to root/project? Pretty please, it can't be so?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `plugin.sbt` file is ignored because you cannot have a `project` subfolder in a sub-project of a multi-project build.

In a [multi-project build](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html#default-root-project),

- The `.sbt` files of the root project, and all `.sbt` files of all sub-projects, are all part of a *single* build definition. The settings defined in a sub-project are just automatically scoped to that project.
- Since there is only one build definition, there is only one project to build that build definition, and that is in the `project/` folder of the root project. All `project/` folders of sub-projects will be ignored.

In your case, moving your `plugin.sbt` to the build root `project` folder should make your plugin appear again.

Furthermore, if you only work on the `core` project, instead of running `sbt` in core, you can run `sbt` in the root project and type `project core` to "move" (actually, scope everything you do) to the core sub-project.

Comment: :.( 

Was afraid of that being the case. That means I only have one "plugin-scope" so say xsbt-web-plugin will pollute the build for my core which  might not be a web project. Feels like a broken architecture to me. The ideal would be able to compose a multi module project by pointing to different projects as is.

Comment: It's not as bad as it seems.  Plugins won't pollute projects that don't import their settings.  With xsbt-web-plugin, you simply omit `WebPlugin.webSettings` from each of the inapplicable submodules.  See the [multi-project branch of xwp-template](https://github.com/earldouglas/xwp-template/blob/multi-project/project/Build.scala) for an example.

Comment: Agreed. However, I still feel this is an architectural problem since it will make it impossible to ever make a aggregation of projects by simply referring to them as aggregates. The submodules are always build-dependent on the supermodule.

Comment: @hedefalk I view it as an architectural problem as well.  SBT docs say a subproject should function as its own unit.  Paraphrased that.  Sad it has not been fixed in 9 months... Will have to join the dev group to notify.

Comment: Can a plugin be added to a single module in a multi module build?